# How to avoid images from expanding my html width and height

Tags: css, reactjs, image, width

I have some svg files with position: "absolute" in my page, but whenever they're positioned close to the corners of my page they end up expanding the width of my Container element (I'm using Material UI React), I've tried using "maxWidth":"100vw" on the page container, with no success, as well as the prop maxWidth="lg" and "md". If possible I'd like the svg or img file to just disappear into the nothing without interacting in any way with its outside container https://gyazo.com/9d3d8cf86748ac434700ac0b0ceaf1c6

Comment: your image doesn't explain much. are you sure it's `position: absolute` check in Dev Tools. if an object is `position: absolute` then it should be removed from it's parent container and won't affect the sizing of the container.

Comment: Hi, basically I have this arrows and images that overflow my html https://gyazo.com/366277f767e22346184132ae6758d574 I added a border to them so that it's easier to appreciate, their position is absolute, but they have so much "blank" space on their sides that it ends up overflowing the whole view

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: <img
      src="mysrc"
        style={{
          height: height,
          width: width,
          position: "absolute",
          top: props.top,
          left: props.left,
          opacity: 0.55,
          Zindex: -2,
          display: "inline",
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          pointerEvents: "none",
          filter: "blur(50px)",
          objectFit: "cover",
        }}
      ></img>

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing something like this?

```
.container {
  /* If for some reason the image doesn't fit, hide the overlap */
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Make image sit within it's container */
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```